# Show X axis on top and bottom in line chart rendered with Chart.js 2.4.0

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart rendered with Chart.js and I display the X axis at the bottom:

```
xAxes: [{  type: 'linear',
           position: 'bottom',
```

I would like to have two X axis, one at the bottom and one at the top.
I see in the documentation that `position` is a string, thus one value only.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but I just had the same problem. Luckily the value of xAxes is an array, so you define multiple axes like this:

```
xAxes: [
    { position: 'top' },
    { position: 'bottom', ... other definitions here ... }
]
```

Comment: Note that above setting should write in options > scales like:
```options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        position: 'top',
                        barPercentage: 1.0,
                        categoryPercentage: 0.5
                    }]
                },
    ....
  }```